# Codename one Upload a picture taken by the camera to amazon s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, codenameone

Original Question

I have tried as you have suggested, there are few things I have run into few issues.
Here are the following I did: filePath = Capture.capturePhoto(1024, -1);

I had issue passing the S3_BUCKET_URL in the MutipartRequest Constructor so I used rq.setUrl(S3_BUCKET_URL)

I had to add rq.setHttpMethod("PUT"); // since I got error as 405: Method was not supported

Finally I got no errors and I did see a sub-folder created under the bucket I created. I set the url as "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket123/test/" I saw test bucket created but image files wasn't uploaded. The folder size wasn't 0 as it showed the size of the file but no image files were found in that sub folder.

When I try to access the folder through S3 explorer I got the the Access Denied. 1. I manually created a sub-folder using S3 explorer and gave the read and write permission yet once the uploadFileToS3 method called from codename I saw the permissions was lost.
2. So I did change the acl to "public-read-write" still same effect.

Please advise if I am missing anything.

Thank you.

---

Modified question 
I have modified the old questions and following this with Sahi's answer.

```
    // Modified the url as following - full path including bucket name and key
    private static final String S3_BUCKET_URL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/myfile.jpg";

    //String filePath = captured from Camera;
        public void uploadFileToS3(String filePath, String uniqueFileName) {
            MultipartRequest rq = new MultipartRequest();
            rq.setUrl(S3_BUCKET_URL);
            //rq.addArgument("acl", "private");
            //rq.addArgument("key", uniqueFileName);
            rq.addData(uniqueFileName, filePath, "image/jpeg");
            rq.setReadResponseForErrors(true);
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(rq);
        }

Now I do see that the file has been uploaded to the bucket as myfile.jpg under my bucket.  The bucket has all the rights since the bucket is given rights to read and write also applied the permissions to sub folders.
Now the myfile.jpg lost all the permissions and I am not able to download that file even though I see it in the bucket.
I accessed it by the url but the file cannot be opened.

I am not sure what I am missing in the header or request. I am really trying to get this working but not getting where I wanted to.  This is very important piece for the app I am working on.  

Please provide any feedback.

Thank you.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Adding code

private static final String S3_BUCKET_URL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/";

When I had the url as above, the my-bucket was created as unknown object (no folder icon) but I did see the file size was actual image size.

```
//String filePath = captured from Camera;
public void uploadFileToS3(String filePath, String uniqueFileName) {
//uniqueFileName including sub folder - subfolder/my-image.jpg
MultipartRequest rq = new MultipartRequest();
rq.setUrl(S3_BUCKET_URL);
rq.addArgument("acl", "public-read-write");
rq.addArgument("key", uniqueFileName);
rq.addData(uniqueFileName, filePath, "image/jpeg");
rq.setReadResponseForErrors(true);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(rq);
}
```

Looks like I am not uploading the object properly. I did go through the amazon document and I wasn't able to find anything related to upload through http.  I am really stuck and I hope to get this resolved.  Would you have any working code that simply uploads to s3?

---

```
More details: I am adding more detail to the question as I am still not able to resolve this.

    // Original S3_BUCKET_URL 
    String S3_BUCKET_URL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/";
    // With this url I am getting 400 : Bad Request Error
    // I added the uniqueFilename (key) to the url as 
    String uniqueFilename = "imageBucket/image12345.jpg";
    String S3_BUCKET_URL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket   /"+uniqueFilename;
    //Now I do see the file I believe it's the file, the 
    //subfolder inherits the rights from bucket (read, write). 
    //Not the image file.
    //When I click on the file using s3 client browser I got message
    //prompted Access Denied.

    // my function to call s3 bucket
    public void takePicture()
    {
        String stringImg = Capture.capturePhoto(1024, -1);    
        MultipartRequest rq = new MultipartRequest();
        rq.setUrl(S3_BUCKET_URL);
        rq.addArgument("key", uniqueFilename );
        rq.addArgument("acl", "public-read-write");
        rq.setHttpMethod("PUT"); // If I don't specify this I am getting 
                                 // 405 : Method Not Allowed Error.
        rq.addData("file", stringImg, "image/jpeg"); 
        //Captured Image from camera
        rq.setFilename("file", uniqueFilename);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue();
    }
```

At this point I believe I have done all the suggested way and I am still getting the same error.  I believe I am not doing anything wrong and I don't want to believe that I am the only one trying to do this :)

I really need your help to get this resolved in order to keep this project.  I am wondering if there is any Amazon s3 sdk or library I can use in codename one.

Please review this and let me know if this really can be achieved by codename one.

Thank you.

Comment: Also when I have the url as S3_BUCKET_URL = "s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/"; I get an error as 400: Bad Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this code and it should work however it depends on a fix to Codename One to deal with some stupid behavior of the Amazon API:

```
Form hi = new Form("Upload");

Button upload = new Button("Upload");
hi.add(upload);
upload.addActionListener(e -> {
    String file = Capture.capturePhoto();
    if(file != null) {
        try {
            String uniqueFileName = "Image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            MultipartRequest rq = new MultipartRequest();
            rq.setUrl("https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/");
            rq.addArgument("key", uniqueFileName);
            rq.addArgument("acl", "private");
            rq.addData("file", file, "image/jpeg");
            rq.setReadResponseForErrors(true);
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(rq);            
            if(rq.getResponseCode() != 200 && rq.getResponseCode() != 204) {
                System.out.println("Error response: " + new String(rq.getResponseData()));
            }
            ToastBar.showMessage("Upload completed", FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO);
        } catch(IOException err) {
            Log.e(err);
        }
    }
});

hi.show();
```

When running the code below (with post) I didn't get the error you described, instead I got an error from Amazon indicating the key wasn't in the right order. Apparently Amazon relies on the order of the submitted fields which is damn stupid. Unfortunately we ignore that order when you add an argument and since this is a post request the code to workaround this is non-trivial.

I've made a fix to Codename One that will respect the natural order in which arguments are added but since we already made this weeks release this will only go in next Friday (December 23rd 2016). So the code above should work as expected following that update.

**Older answer for reference**

I haven't tested this but something like this should work:

```
private static final String S3_BUCKET_URL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/";


public void uploadFileToS3(String filePath, String uniqueFileName) {
    MultipartRequest rq = new MultipartRequest(S3_BUCKET_URL);
    rq.addArgument("acl", "private");
    rq.addArgument("key", uniqueFileName);
    rq.addData("file", filePath, "image/jpeg");
    rq.setFilename("file", uniqueFileName);
    rq.setReadResponseForErrors(true);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(rq);
}
```

Notice that this doesn't do authorization so it assumes the bucket is accessible at least for write.

Comment: I'm guessing that you got that issue because of the acl/private option I had there. Try experimenting with other values. In our case we needed very restricted write-only access and the read is for very specific users.

Comment: Hi Shai, 
thank you for the fast response.  I'll follow your instruction on asking questions and updating comments.
I did try rq.addArgument("acl", "public-read-write")  like mentioned above, still no luck. I'll further investigate and please advise if you have come across anything.
Thank you.

Comment: HI Shai,
I have edited the question with my finding.  Please review.

Comment: Notice that when you edit the question it is good practice to leave the original question in place and add details below. Otherwise people arriving at the question won't understand the answers. Notice my S3 URL doesn't include the filename at the end as the filename is within the submission (key).

Comment: Hi Shai, I have included the original question as you have suggested.  
I did have the filename in the key in the beginning. but once the file is uploaded I didn't really see the filename.  I changed the acl to "public-read-write".  Still prompting Access denied when I try to download that file. I'll add my code to the original question and comment on each line.

Comment: Reviewing our code again I think my `addData` call was wrong. The file should have the property name `file` so it should look something like this: `    rq.addData("file", filePath, "image/jpeg");  rq.setFilename("file", uniqueFileName);`

Comment: Hi Shai, Thank you for continuous support and feedback.  I have updated the question with more detail.  Please read the comments I have put under each line of code.  I hope this will give you better picture of what I am running into.  Hopefully I can get this resolved or please advise if there any other way to do this.
I simply wanted to upload an image captured by the camera to the amazon S3 Bucket.  I believe this has been done by so many others.  Please provide your feedback
Thank you.

Comment: See my revised answer

Comment: Hi Shai,
Thank you for the detail response and taking the time to test the code.  For some reason I am still getting 400 bad request error.  I have exact code as you have and no luck.
I did create a bucket cn1test and folder images.  
url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cn1test/"
key: "images/image123.jpg"
With all the other settings I am running into 400 bad request. I guess I'll have to wait till the update next Friday.  If you ever have a chance please check the bucket url.
Again thank you so much for the support.

Comment: The update is required, check out the response from amazon using `String error = new String(request.getResponseData());` this is often a detailed error message you can use to track the issue. Since the code is already committed to git you can use our sources directly and see this right now: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html

Comment: Shai, as you have instructed I tried to capture the error, I got null exception error. Interestingly I came to know amazon responses differently with different region bucket.
the url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cn1test/" (Us Standard region) returns 400 bad request (request.getResponseData() is null)

the url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rst6/" (Oregon region) displays NullPointerExcetpion on request.getResponseData()

I'll try to get the source code or I'll wait till this Friday release.  
Thank you.

Comment: You need to use `addToQueueAndWait()` like I did in my example where I checked the error response...

Comment: Hi Shai, I got the following error:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Bucket POST must contain a field named 'key'.  If it is specified, please check the order of the fields.</Message><ArgumentName>key</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue></ArgumentValue></Error>

I am getting the same error as you are.  I guess I have to wait till this Friday for the update.

Comment: Hi Shai, I have updated the codename one plugin as I started the Netbeans IDE.  I am still getting the order issue from amazon response.  Please advise if I am doing anything wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: The update isn't in the early morning. Go to Codename One Settings under the basic section select Update Client Libs to get the latest version of the libraries (not the plugin).

Comment: Hi Shai, Thank you for the response.   It works well when I save it directly under the bucket but if I add a folder name in the key field, the file is being saved to the root level bucket still with the folder name added to the file
String uniqueFileName = "Image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
Saves with the file name "Image1483080423837.jpg"
When I include the folder name as follows:
String uniqueFileName = "images/Image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"; It saves to the root bucket with the following file name
"images%2FImage1483080684852.jpg"
Thanks

Comment: For that argument use `addArgumentNoEncoding`. BTW don't forget to accept the answer now that it works...

Comment: Shai, Thank yo so much for all the support.  Finally it works well.

Comment: This still does not work for me, I always get java.io.IOException: Error writing to server. Any ideas why ?

Comment: It's a bit of a long thread, I suggest opening a new question with details. Inspect your network monitor which should include the exact error message from Amazon and make sure you set the buckets correctly

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate a presigned URL on you server:
2. Pass thar URL to the mobile client.

   ```
   IAmazonS3 client;
   client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
   // Generate a pre-signed URL.
   GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
       {
          BucketName = bucketName,
           Key        = objectKey,
           Verb       = HttpVerb.PUT,
           Expires    = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
       };
   string url = null;
   url = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
   ```
3. Mobile client can upload a file to that URL using old plain PUT HTTP request:

   ```
   // Upload a file using the pre-signed URL.
   HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
   httpRequest.Method = "PUT";
   using (Stream dataStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
   {
      // Upload object.
   }

   HttpWebResponse response = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
   ```

You can take a look at official documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html

Comment: Thank you Sergey, I am actually trying to implement this on Codename One which is Java based framework.  
Hopefully it is supported.
Thanks again