# codenameone REST API POST request body

Tags: java, rest, http, mobile, codenameone

Im trying to call a POST method from a REST API on AWS API Gateway.The API is correctly called from command line using curl(for POST)and the browser using GET so i know its working fine, but i cant seem to find the correct way to call POST method on codename one using ConnectionRequest class, reading the documentation theres addArgument() and setRequestBody() and they say , they are exclusive, so i tried both , but my results are:

- setRequestBody() : seems like it doesnt send anything to the request, tried sending the same JSON requestBody that i send on curl, the API responds but the requestBody is "undefined"(checked on AWS API Gateway log), tried also request.addRequestHeader("test", "test"); and again, the headers are "undefined" in AWS logs, but are displayed when the API is called on command line.
- addArgument(): the API resturns "400 bad request".

Im using  request.setPost(true); 
but theres also setHttpMethod(String value); so i am not sure if i am doing it right.

Whats the correct way of calling a POST REST and send it parameters? Is there any way to debug the request being sent? like printing the equivalent CURL call or somethint like that? Or theres any way to perform  the CURL request directly on CN1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question,after Shai Almong help, and some testing, the correct way its(i was missing setContentType call) :

```
setPost(true);
setContentType('application/json');
setRequestBody("parameters in json format");
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the exact same thing as it's a multipart upload but I have working AWS [upload code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094606/codename-one-upload-a-picture-taken-by-the-camera-to-amazon-s3-bucket), if you update the question (and comment below) I can include code to do the exact curl request in Codename One.

As to the question calling `setPost(true)` is enough as it will set the post method implicitly. The http method is useful if you want to do something like `PUT`.

Picking request body vs. argument depends on the type of request you have.

Comment: Thank you Shai, already updated the question , for the "picking request vs argument" , since it's a POST i thought the correct way will be using request body , but when trying it and checking the logs on AWS side, it is received as "undefined", if i perform the same request on curl, with the same request body , it is received successfully ,so googling the case found another question here on Stack Overflow where you mentioned that on POST you could also use addArgument() , tried it but returns "bad request" so none of them is working for me, am i missing something?

Comment: I found what i was missing, it was a call to : setContentType() , now its working through setRequestBody